# How do i manually fail an angular $http requests in an interceptor

Tags: angularjs, http, interceptor, angular-promise

So i have a server that is returning 200 as a response every time. I need to check the response for an error `response.data.error` If i find an error i need to send the http request to the catch methods in my application code.

Here is an example of what i want to happen..

interceptor code

```
// interceptor code
{
  response:function(response){
    if (response.data.error) {
      return $q.reject(response)
    }else{
      return response
    }
  },
  responseError:function(rejection){
    // error handling logic

    return $q.reject(rejection)
  }
}
```

app code

```
// application code
$http.get('/api/stuff')
  .then(function(){
    // do success stuff
  }).catch(function(){
    // the function i want to run!!!
  })
```

Comment: What happens if you put a random **url**, like `$http.get('aaa')`? Does it calls the `catch`?

Comment: The posted code should work as expected. Please, provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with fiddle/plunk if you have problems with this approach.

Comment: Ok soooo its gotta be something with my application. because i just made a plunkr and it worked https://plnkr.co/edit/ZpwSMW66EnUtP78QhVV9?p=preview

Comment: So is this resolved then? If yes, mark/create correct answer yourself or remove question as in this format is has no use to anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it was more of a silly mistake. Here is what i did wrong.
like a dumb i returned inside of a function instead of directly inside of the response. so what i ended up doing is creating a flag and if that flag was true then return directly on the response function.

interceptor code

```
// interceptor code
{
  response:function(response){
    myCustomErrorFunction(){
      if (response.data.error) {
        return $q.reject(response)
      }else{
        return response
      }
    }
  },
  responseError:function(rejection){
    // error handling logic

    return $q.reject(rejection)
  }
}
```

app code

```
// application code
$http.get('/api/stuff')
  .then(function(){
    // do success stuff
  }).catch(function(){
    // the function i want to run!!!
  })
```

Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try catching the error by:

```
$http.get('/api/stuff')
  .then(function(data){
    console.log(data); // do success stuff
  }, function(error){
      console.log(error); // will catch your error I hope
  }
```

I dont think that `.catch` will cacth it, you need to preform the check in the `.then` block.